# Is it possible to implement html5 <video> tag in asp.net 2010 web page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I tried to implement html5 `<video>` tag in asp.net 2010 web form (ex: http://localhost/SampleWebsite/test.aspx) but its not supporting.

I tried in all browsers like IE9, latest Mozilla, Chrome, Opera. Its working fine in pure HTML.

Here one thing even if I take the HTML file in my visual studio solution (ex: http://localhost/Samplewebsite/test.html) its not working.

Can any one please provide your valuable suggestions and if possible provide with example.

Sorry guys the link I provided is dummy link just for your information please verify the below .aspx code that I implement in .aspx page in .net framework 4.0 with visual studio 2010

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">  
    <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" />  
    <source src="videos/Test-movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />  
</video>
```

I struck with another one is. Is it possible to prepare a Images slideshow using html5  tag if possible can any one please provide the complete details with example.

Comment: how did you implement it? what version of asp.net are you using? we cant access your localhost...

Comment: sort answer: Of course you can. Longer answer: add the content of the video tag and/or the error you are getting so that someone can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is absolutely possible - for a walkthrough including sample/source see [here](http://www.misfitgeek.com/use-html5-video-tags-in-your-asp-net-applications/).

For ASP.NET MVC a nice option is to use [these opensource components](http://mvchtml5.codeplex.com/).

Comment: "I struck with another one is Is it possible to prepare a Images slideshow using html5 tag if possible can any one please provide the complete details with example. Thanks in advance."

Comment: @BhanuPrakashInturi basically on SO it is "one question per question" thus ask a new question...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible .

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: "I struck with another one is Is it possible to prepare a Images slideshow using html5 tag if possible can any one please provide the complete details with example. Thanks in advance."